# Toyota Prius 2010 Has No Spare Tire

Tags: toyota, tires

I recently bought a 2010 used Toyota Prius from local dealer in [Jordan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan), the dealer claims this edition imported from Germany (even the user manuals are in Dutch).

The wired part unlike the USA/Japan editions I have no place for a spare tire in the back trunk which at the first I thought the spare tire is stolen but after I browsed the Dutch manual (looking for images only; I don't speak the language) it seems that there are some editions where Toyota does not provide a spare tire but rather supply a **[Tyre repair kit](http://accessories.toyota.ie/index.php/catalogue/detail/tyre-repair-kit)**

The bad news The Air Compressor (the kit’s hose) is missing.

I have tried to get in touch with Toyota Spare Parts Centre to buy a new Air Compressor but they don't have it in stock and they asked me if I can get the Part number of the Air Compressor ( I know they're somehow lousy).

Can anyone help me to get the item part number, or at least if I can get it the OEM online.

Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dealership is going to tell you that this kit is going to have to be ordered complete. They usually do not allow ordering of only a single part of the kit. I handle these situations by calling the dealership and asking to speak to the Sales Manager. The moment you get them involved he will jump on the salesman's back. Since a big part of any salesman is repeat business. And if the salesman is lagging on getting back in touch with you since he already got his commission check. Then give the issue a little push.

It is best not to involve any company or suppliers outside of the actual dealership that you handled the purchase of the vehicle. Unless you have to. And if it came to that then you should call Toyota Headquarters and really push the issue. Since worst case scenario you'd be stuck on the side of the road with your hands in your pockets since the *dealership* that sold you the vehicle refused to supply all the parts needed in case of an emergency. The last place anyone wants to be is sitting in their car late at night on the side of the highway with other vehicles passing by at 60+mph.

I wanted to make sure to put an emphasis on the safety concern. Hope I did a good job at that.

In the mean time I did manage to stumble upon [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ELECTRIC-12V-AIR-PUMP-TYRE-INFLATOR-COMPRESSOR-250-PSI-TOYOTA-PRIUS-HATCHBACK-/130672748828?pt=UK_Air_Tools_and_Compressors&hash=item1e6cb3e91c) I'm not sure if your compressor is the same one or not since this car is an imported from Germany.

The dealership should have supplied you with the proper English documentation. **What if something happens that you need to reference the manual? Or if a light illuminates on the cluster that you don't recognize and it ends up being a ""low oil"" light or `"low coolant"` light and you end up stranded or even worse, damaging the vehicle when it could have been avoided?!** *(This is just an extreme example)*

I also believe it's against the rules for a dealership to sell a vehicle without the spare kits complete (not 100% sure on that). But I do know for a fact that every vehicle sold, if it is sold `as is` or `certified` it still must go through an inspection from a "certified" technician and that checklist involves checking to ensure that all the components in the spare kit are there and work.

Comment: I don't think secondhand cars are required to have all kit. As long as they're roadworthy, they can be sold. But it obviously differs per country.

Comment: I can see that being true for a private sale but not for something sold by a dealership. It doesn't cost them much time/effort to simply order a kit and manuals in the proper language.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a can of [Tyre Weld](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Holts-HT3YA-Tyreweld-Emergency-Puncture/dp/B000Y8WB8W) which would inflate a flat tyre and seal the puncture on amazon. It's much less messy than having to wrestle a piece of sticky earthworm (at least, that's what it looks like) into a hole at the side of the road.

It's going to be much cheaper than whatever the dealer charges you for a replacement kit.

Comment: Juann Strauss: you are absolutely right, I have recently purchased one and had it on my trunk, I hope that I am not gonna need it, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

A number of European cars of late have not included a spare wheel - however, this trend has changed and a number of car manufacturers are being forced by their user base to supply spare tires.

The reasoning behind the lack of a spare tire is that it decreases weight in the vehicle, thus improving the MPG when going for official testing - the MPG and emissions are a very big deal for the European market. The lack of a spare tire also has the lovely side effect of reducing the cost to the manufacturer as they can simply supply you with a pump and a "can of goo".

The car that I bought was supplied with a "can of goo" that you use with the compressor / air pump to inflate the tire. There are two large downsides to this method.

1. The "can of goo" expires, and needs to be replaced every 3 years (in my case)
2. You **CANNOT** and **MUST NEVER** use the goo when there is a hole or rip in the sidewall of the tyre.

A solution, one that I use myself, is to get a large can of TyreWeld (or similar, pressurized liquid latex) and keep it in the boot.